# Removing a retired service entry using API calls

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

I'm trying to clean a retired version of an older service I created in CAM, but it's still showing up in the ICP catalog. Is there some way to clear this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A retired service in CAM will be displayed in ICP catalog. This is a known issue and we are working with ICP to resolve it.  Once retired you have to delete the service via the API as mentioned here:

`Delete a service - You can only delete a draft service. After you publish a service, you cannot delete it. However, the workaround to delete a published service is to retire the service and delete it by using API.`
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_2.1.0.3/cam_managing_services.html

Issuing a DELETE to /service will clean up the entry from ICP Catalog, but do note that the broker takes some time to update the catalog in ICP, on the order of 15 min:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_2.1.0.3/cam_common_API.html#getlistservices